# Problem with \acused from acronym package: Not in list of acronyms

Tags: verbatim, acronyms

When using the acronym package, acronyms marked with `\acused{AC}` are not contained in the list of acronyms.

However, I also cannot place `\ac{AC}`, `\acs{AC}`, or `\acl{AC}` since all of it is explained in a verbatim environment.

Is there a way to have the acronym in the list without printing anything outside of the `verbatim` environment?

Minimum non working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                                AC                             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
\end{verbatim}
\label{acro:AC}
\acused{AC}
\ac{AC2}
\begin{acronym}[AC2]
\acro{AC}[AC]{Acronym}
\acro{AC2}[AC2]{Acronym 2}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

This shows AC2 in acronym list, but not AC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\acronymused{AC}` instead of `\acused{AC}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                                AC                             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
\end{verbatim}
\label{acro:AC}
\acronymused{AC}
\ac{AC2}
\begin{acronym}[AC2]
  \acro{AC}[AC]{Acronym}
  \acro{AC2}[AC2]{Acronym 2}
  \acro{AC3}[AC3]{Acronym 3}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the list of acronyms is in the frontmatter, then `\acronymused{AC}` should also go into the `.aux` file. This can be done by `\AC@logged{AC}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[AC2]
  \acro{AC}[AC]{Acronym}
  \acro{AC2}[AC2]{Acronym 2}
  \acro{AC3}[AC3]{Acronym 3}
\end{acronym}

\begin{verbatim}
 0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                                AC                             |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
\end{verbatim}
\label{acro:AC}
\makeatletter
\AC@logged{AC}
\makeatother
\ac{AC2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\acronymused` didn't work for me, but including the label manually with `\acused` or `\acsu` did.

Comment: Though the back reference from the list of acronyms will point to the beginning of the section rather than the exact occurrence of the acronym, as it does with your average use of `\ac`

Comment: @ThomasH I cannot reproduce this, adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` after `acronym` in the last source example creates a link `AC2` that jumps correcly above the entry `AC2` in the acronym list. (Version of `acronym`: 2012/10/29 v1.38)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove `printonlyused` from `\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}`. The default behavior of the acronym package is to print all acronyms, including "unused" ones. So you'd use this:

`\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}`

Check the manual for more information: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf